# Passing data from directive to controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm looking for a way (a function) to take data from a clicked element from an ng-repeat list and pass it into a controller.

My dirctive gets the data like so:

```
var defaultFormat = scope.release.format;
    musicInfoService.getReleaseVersions(scope.release.id)
    .success(function(data) {
        if (data.error) return;

        var format = data.versions,
          formats = scope.release.format;

        if (format !== '') {
          formats = format;
        }

        scope.defaultFormat = formats;
        dataService.setItems(scope.defaultFormat);
      })
      .error(function($scope) {
        scope.basicFormat = scope.release.format;
        dataService.setItems(scope.basicFormat);
     });
```

And it stores it in a factory:

```
app.factory('dataService', [function($scope){
   var _items= "";
   return { 
          setItems:function(value){
             _items=value;
          },
          getItems:function(){
             return _items;
          }
  };
}]);
```

On the controller side, the function will trigger getItems, but it just doesn't work.

```
function VersionController($scope, dataService) {
  $scope.versions = dataService.getItems();
  console.log($scope.versions);
}
```

Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GBdvtN6ayo59017rLKPs?p=preview). The list that appears under every album name should be appearing into the box that opens upon click, but the box will only show the data from the last element of the lit (the last data stored into the scope.basicFormat or scope.defaultFormat variables), so the conclusion I'm getting is that so far, the function won't trigger the setItems for each element.

Comment: The plnkr doesn't work :|

Comment: @Narretz - to me it works fine! :S

Comment: ah, sorry my noscript blocked the url with your resources

Comment: Hmm, I am sorry, I don't really understand what the problem is. Neither from your description, nor from the code. I enter an Artist, A list appears, I click on an artist, and a list of releases appears. I can filter the list. I can also search for another artist, and everything displays.

Comment: When u click on release, the version list that appears doesn't correspond to the release :/

Comment: You can delete your previous question, it is the same as this question and my answer answers it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you call `musicInfoService.getReleaseVersions` thousands times, but the `dataService.setItems` function doesn't distinguish these calls and always overwrites results. That's why only the last result is shown.

At first fix your data service factory so that it takes the `key` parameter:

```
app.factory('dataService', [function($scope){
    var _items= {};
    return { 
          setItems:function(key, value){
             _items[key] = value;
          },
          getItems:function(key){
             return _items[key] ? _items[key] : _items["basic"];
          }
    };
}]);
```

Then update your `setItems` calls:

```
    // ...
    scope.defaultFormat = formats;
    dataService.setItems(scope.release.id.toString(), scope.defaultFormat);
})
.error(function($scope) {
    scope.basicFormat = scope.release.format;
    dataService.setItems("basic", scope.basicFormat);
});
```

And update your `getItems` call:

```
$scope.versions = dataService.getItems($scope.release.id.toString());
```

After this your Plunker example works.

Comment: Hi Vorrtex!
It works but there's a glitch, if the $http call comes back an error, the basicFormat won't appear. I can work around it, and add a                     <li ng-show="">{{release.format}}</li>, but how to I make the ng-show work only when the http call failed?

Comment: Also would be nice to minimize server calls and only make the query if the item is clicked, but all my attempts failed. If u have any pointers i'd be very appreciated!

Comment: @Eric Mitjans It's because the basic format returns different and strange strings like "cDr" or "CD, Album". But `dataService.setItems` expects an array, not a string, that's why it doesn't work. But I don't know what you mean by basic and what value is expected. As to minimizing server calls, create a new question on this site like "How to call a function from a directive when I click an image?", it will be easier to answer there than in comments, and also the question will be visible to more people.

Comment: As I see, in case of error you set `scope.basicFormat`, but do not set this value in case of success (it is undefined). So you can check `Boolean(basicFormat) == true` which means that there was an error. Also you can introduce a more clear name for such variable.